# Не запускается файл через WinRM

Tags: powershell

### Не запускается файл или приложение через Winrm
Использую следующий метод:
Enter-PSSession compname
cd "c:\users\admin\desktop"
start file.exe

получаю следующую ошибку:
This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock{c:\users\admin\desktop\file.exe}
```

или

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1 -ScriptBlock{cd c:\users\admin\desktop\ ; .\file.exe}
```

Comment: Благодарю за варианты, но на том и на другом выдает следующую ошибку: "[CompName] Connecting to remote server CompName failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For
 more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (sh-agnihotri:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken"

Comment: Компьютеры в домене?

Comment: Да в домене, у меня права админа.

Comment: Странно. Но если пускает по Enter-PSSession, то дальше можете вбивать ```c:\users\admin\desktop\file.exe```